# How to create a select where count is not zero in MySQL

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

Here's what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to select from a forum views table all of the `user_id`s where there are 5 or more records.  That's fairly easy (this is Zend):

```
$objCountSelect = $db->select()
    ->from(array('v' =>'tbl_forum_views'), 'COUNT(*) AS count')
    ->where('u.id = v.user_id')
    ->having('COUNT(user_id) >= ?', 5)
;
```

But I need to somehow connect this to my users table.  I don't want to return a result if the count is greater than 5.  I tried this:

```
$objSelect = $db->select()
     ->from(array('u' => 'tbl_users'), array(
          'id as u_id',
          'count' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $objCountSelect . ')'),
       ))
;
```

But that returns a record for every user, leaving blank the count if it's less than or equal to 5.  How do I exclude the rows where the count is less than or equal to 5?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but wanted to post the answer in case someone else had the same issue.  I added:

`->having('count > 0')`

to the second select and now it works.